# How to remove underline rule on dropdown options?

Tags: css

I've got the following DOM :

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="a">
        <option class="foo">1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="b">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

That I want to do is to underline the `optgroup`'s label, but not `option`'s one.

So I wrote this CSS:

```
 optgroup {
     text-align: left;
     color: #222;
     text-decoration: underline;
 }

 optgroup option {
     color: red;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

optgroup option.foo {
     color: green;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

And I get the following output (from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8d3G/)):

[image]

What did I miss to remove the option's underline?
I'm working on Firefox 17.

Comment: there are not any underlines on both optgroup and option in Chrome, looks like you just need to support FireFox?

Comment: Force refresh or clear cache? It should work as the syntax is correct. Check Firebug or Inspect Element to see the styles being applied and see if the stylesheet is being loaded correctly.

Comment: @KodleeYin the syntax is correct because you suppose that feature is supported, once the feature is not supported, we can't change anything.

Comment: @KingKing actually it seems to be a cross-browser compatibility problem. Maybe I should forget underline styling...  Do you know if there is some CSS instruction which have good compatibility with `optgroup`?

Comment: Looks like some buggy Firefox behaviour. Depending on your requirements, you could botch it behave like you want http://jsfiddle.net/j8d3G/3/

Comment: @KodleeYin so go ahead and make a working demo ***meeting*** the OP's requirement. I have to agree that the OP's code is perfect but it does not work, so that feature (underline optgroup's label but does not underline items) is not supported.

Comment: @Fractaliste looks like the MLeFevre's fiddle works, although it's some kind of hack. However it appears that only FireFox supports underlines in SELECT, if you want some rich style SELECT elements, just try customizing it yourself or search on the web, there are many demos about custom SELECT as well as complete libraries.

Comment: I would also recommend using a custom SELECT instead. SELECT's are notoriously time-consuming/impossible to style consistently across different browsers. That solution I posted literally only makes it look correct in FireFox, it still displays incorrectly in Chrome, probably other browsers as well.

Comment: @MLeFevre Good job, do not hesitate to post it as an answer. I'm going to look after custom SELECTs,... Thank's for your tips!

Comment: @Fractaliste It's not really an answer (at least not a good answer), merely a hack. I think the correct answer would be as King King suggested and use a custom SELECT. They're easier to style and would be a allround better solution in the long run.

Comment: These one seems to work only in ff `optgroup:before{border-bottom:solid 1px #000;}`

Comment: @Alek That solution is better than my one. Although I think you'd have to specify the width of the border to get the exact desired behaviour Fractaliste was after http://jsfiddle.net/j8d3G/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno if this suits you and works only in firefox. But i think your example is only for firefox so try this out:

```
    optgroup::before{
        content: attr(label);
        border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
        width:10px;
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8d3G/19/)